# Google App Engine time out?

Tags: google-app-engine, timeout

In a Google App Engine app I used the following lines to read a page from a site :

```
  String Url="http://...",line,Result="";

  URL url=new URL(Url+"?r="+System.currentTimeMillis());
  BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

  while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) { Result+=line+"\n"; }
  reader.close();
```

But I got the following error :

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (f5e2889605d27d42) started at 2011/09/07 03:20:41.458 UTC and was still executing at 2011/09/07 03:21:30.888 UTC.
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1326)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:276)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:82)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.TimedFuture.get(TimedFuture.java:55)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:69)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:177)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.access$000(ApiProxyImpl.java:56)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:150)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:148)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Seems it took longer than it would like to wait, what can I do if that site is slow ?

Comment: This is a request timeout, which happens after 30 seconds. Since URLFetch requests are limited to 10 seconds, you must be doing more than just this one call. What are you doing?

Comment: Yes, I was getting page contents from 6 categories and see where my NMJava is ranked, so it took longer as it goes through each page to find the name NMJava and calculates where it stands over all.

Comment: Have you considered using asynchronous URLFetch? That'll let you do all the requests in parallel.

Comment: "asynchronous URLFetch" ? How to do that, any sample code ?

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/URLFetchService.html#fetchAsync(com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [DeadlineExceededException](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/apphosting/api/DeadlineExceededException.html) is thrown when your code, handling the request to your web application takes over 30 seconds to process. Presumably your code is taking a while to process because of the length of time it had to wait to receive data from some other site.

You can create a task on a [task queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html) to fetch and process that data, and change your web request/response flow to reply with progress on your task.

Comment: The exception being encountered is a request deadline, not a URLFetch deadline.

Comment: Woo, seems complicated, any sample code to do this on Google App Engine site ? It would be very helpful.

Comment: An example of using a queue is http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codeLabExercise3.html#TaskQueue

Comment: I'd like to point out that the default timeout is now 60 seconds: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine#quotas_and_limits

Comment: besides the change to 60 seconds change above, switching to [basic or manual](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling) scaling will allow for 24 hours now, and switching to GAE Flexible will give a 60 minute deadline

Answer (score 4):

If your code is running inside a request handler, then by default there is an App-Engine-enforced 60 second deadline. You can't change it. See the "Deadlines" row / "automatic scaling" column of the chart on this page under "Scaling types":

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

However, this code will be able to run for some hours if you change your module to use "manual scaling" and a "B1"-"B4" instance. Example:

**default/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>myapp</application>
  <module>default</module>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <instance-class>B1</instance-class>
  <manual-scaling>
    <instances>1</instances>
  </manual-scaling>
</appengine-web-app>
```

On this type of instance, your requests will typically not time out for hours. (The documentation claims that the deadline is "indefinite".)

Comment: This answer should be on top !! I just want to add: If your need is a worker, you better create a new service with `manual_scaling` and let your default service with `automatic_scaling` feature.